# Double tailed arrows in Tikz cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Is there any way to create an arrow such that it has two tails in the same fashion that

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=10ex, column sep=10ex]  
   V \arrow[two heads]{r}W    
\end{tikzcd}
```

creates a double headed arrow?
Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: @samcarter thank you for the edit. It is my first time using this site.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define new arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  two tails/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd double to[reversed]-tikzcd to}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
V \arrow[r, two tails] & W
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]